# Maximal abelian extension and tamely ramify extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ a finite place of $K$ lying above a prime number $p$. Assume further that $v$ is unramified over $p$. If $K^{ab}$ is the maximal abelian extension let $w$ be a valuation extending $v$.

Let $K^{ab}_w,K_v$ be the completion of $K^{ab}$ and $K$ with respect to $w$ and $v$.

When I consider the extension $K^{ab}_w/K_v$ is it true that it is tame?

Comment: Does adjoining $p$-power roots of unity to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ result in tamely ramified extensions?

Comment: I know that if I add the $p$-th roots of unity to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ this extension is totally ramified

Comment: The dichotomy is between tamely vs. wildly ramified. Adjoining to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the roots of unity of prime-to-$p$ order gives the maximal unramified extension $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{nr}}$. Adjoining on top of this all radicals $\sqrt[r]{p}$ with $p \nmid r$ gives a tamely (and, of course, totally) ramified extension $K_p^t / \mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{nr}}$. Adjoining any further elements gives wildly ramified extensions of $K_p^t$.

Comment: @LSpice: It was indeed rhetorical, as a form of hint.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov, then I'll delete the answer.